# How to make EF core db connection faster?

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, database-connection

I'm creating an Android app using Xamarin Forms and C#. I'm using Ef core to connect to database but every time I open a new connection it takes a lot of time. Is there a way to speed the process?

I'm creating a new instance of the context using DependencyService. Is it ok?

```
this.context = DependencyService.Get<MobileFitnessContext>();
```

Comment: Microsoft has some good [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.0) on increasing performance. You may benefit from reading the section about [pooling connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.0#pool-http-connections-with-httpclientfactory).

Comment: My biggest problem is context initializing when the user is logging. Do you know what to do to speed this up?

Comment: Your code should have some time-consuming operations,could you please some code snippets about the context initializing?

Comment: How big is your database model? In term of tables and fields...

Answer (score 0):

The first query on EF takes lots of time. it needs to initialize DbContext to find out tables/columns and relationship between those, etc.

To avoid this you can query in background once the app is loaded and before your first query. So at the time of the first query, your DbContext is initialized and does not take time.